# How to get all 24 rotations of a 3-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, rotation

I have a 3-dimensional array. Think of it as a brick. There are 24 possible rotations of this brick (that keep its edges parallel to coordinate axes). How do I generate all corresponding 3-dimensional arrays?

Comment: you should make an attempt yourself...

Comment: @MitchWheat- This is a hard problem!  I think I'd get stuck pretty quickly even if I did give this an effort.

Answer (score 22):

A die (half a pair of dice) is handy for observing the 24 different orientations, and can suggest operation sequences to generate them.  You will see that any of six faces can be uppermost, and the sides below can be rotated into four different cardinal directions.  Let us denote two operations: “*turn*” and “*roll*”, where *turn* rotates the die about the z axis from one cardinal to the next, and *roll* rotates the die 90° away from you, so the away-face becomes the bottom face and the near face the top.  These operations can be expressed using rotation matrices as mentioned in the answer of Felipe Lopes, or can be expressed as simple functions that when given (x,y,z) return (-y,x,z) or (x,z,-y), respectively.

Anyhow, if you place the die with 1 on the near face, 2 at right, and 3 on top, you will find that the following sequence of steps generates the twelve different orientations with 1, 2, or 3 spots on top: RTTTRTTTRTTT.  Then the sequence RTR exposes 6, 4, 5 where 1, 2, 3 originally were, and a repeat of the sequence RTTTRTTTRTTT generates the twelve orientations with 4, 5, or 6 spots on top.  The mentioned sequence is embedded in the following python code.

```py
def roll(v): return (v[0],v[2],-v[1])
def turn(v): return (-v[1],v[0],v[2])
def sequence (v):
    for cycle in range(2):
        for step in range(3):  # Yield RTTT 3 times
            v = roll(v)
            yield(v)           #    Yield R
            for i in range(3): #    Yield TTT
                v = turn(v)
                yield(v)
        v = roll(turn(roll(v)))  # Do RTR

p = sequence(( 1, 1, 1))
q = sequence((-1,-1, 1))
for i in sorted(zip(p,q)):
    print i
```

The rationale for printing out a sorted list of transformed pairs of points is twofold: (i) any face orientation can be specified by the locations of two of its corners; (ii) it then is easy to check for uniqueness of each pair, eg by piping output to `uniq`.

Here is how the sorted output begins:

```
((-1, -1, -1), (-1, 1, 1))
((-1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1))
((-1, -1, -1), (1, 1, -1))
((-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1))
((-1, -1, 1), (1, -1, -1))
((-1, -1, 1), (1, 1, 1))
((-1, 1, -1), (-1, -1, 1))
((-1, 1, -1), (1, -1, -1))
((-1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1))
```

Answer (score 7):

Let X rotate 90 degrees around the X-axis and Y rotate 90 degrees around the Y-axis then the 24 possible unique combinations are (all possible combinations up to 5 rotations are given except those with four times the same rotation (eg XXXX, XXXXY XYYYY, etc):

```
1.  I
2.  X
3.  Y
4.  XX = YXXY
5.  XY
6.  YX
7.  YY = XYYX
8.  XXX = XYXXY = YXXYX = YXYXY = YYXYY
9.  XXY = YXXYY = YYYXX
10. XYX = YXY
11. XYY = XXYYX = YYXXX
12. YXX = XXYYY = YYXXY
13. YYX = XXXYY = XYYXX
14. YYY = XXYXX = XYXYX = XYYXY = YXYYX
15. XXXY
16. XXYX = XYXY = YXYY
17. XXYY = YYXX
18. XYXX = YXYX = YYXY
19. XYYY
20. YXXX
21. YYYX
22. XXXYX = XXYXY = XYXYY = YXYYY
23. XYXXX = YXYXX = YYXYX = YYYXY
24. XYYYX = YXXXY
```

Of course you can use any two 90 degree rotations in place of the X and Y. For example, Y and Z.

Or, if you also use Z, a 90 degree rotation around the Z axis then 4 rotations suffice:

```
1.  I
2.  X = YXZ
3.  Y = ZYX
4.  Z = XZY
5.  XX = XYXZ = YXXY = YXYZ = YXZX = YYZZ = YZXZ = ZXXZ = ZZYY
6.  XY = YZ = ZX = XZYX = YXZY = ZYXZ
7.  XZ = XXZY = YXZZ = YYYX = ZYYY
8.  YX = XZZZ = YYXZ = ZYXX = ZZZY
9.  YY = XXZZ = XYYX = YZYX = ZXYX = ZYXY = ZYYZ = ZYZX = ZZXX
10. ZY = XXXZ = XZYY = YXXX = ZZYX
11. ZZ = XXYY = XYZY = XZXY = XZYZ = XZZX = YYXX = YZZY = ZXZY
12. XXX
13. XXY = XYZ = XZX = YZZ = ZXZ
14. XXZ = ZYY
15. XYX = YXY = YYZ = YZX = ZXX
16. XYY = YZY = ZXY = ZYZ = ZZX
17. XZZ = YYX
18. YXX = ZZY
19. YYY
20. ZZZ
21. XXXY = XXYZ = XXZX = XYZZ = XZXZ = YZZZ = ZXZZ = ZYYX
22. XXYX = XYXY = XYYZ = XYZX = XZXX = YXYY = YYZY = YZXY = YZYZ = YZZX = ZXXY = ZXYZ = ZXZX = ZYZZ = ZZXZ
23. XYXX = XZZY = YXYX = YYXY = YYYZ = YYZX = YZXX = ZXXX
24. XYYY = YXXZ = YZYY = ZXYY = ZYZY = ZZXY = ZZYZ = ZZZX
```

These 24 matrices all exist of three column vectors that each exist of two zeroes and a minus one or plus one. On every row there are also exactly two zeroes. As such, they can easily be generated: the first column vector has six possibilities ((1,0,0), (-1,0,0), (0,-1,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,-1) and (0,0,1)), this corresponds to moving the positive X-axis to the positive or negative x, y or z axis. The second column vector only has four possibilities because it must contain a zero where the first column has a non-zero value. Finally the third column vector has only one place left where its plus or minus one can be. This gives 6 * 4 * 2 = 48 matrices, half of them mirror the original as well however (they are combination of a mirror and optionally a rotation). Hence only 24 are pure rotations. The matrices that are mirror operations will have a determinant equal to -1, the determinant of the pure rotations is 1.

Comment: Note that using the first elements of the "Z" example will not produce 24 unique vectors. The top example does.
Here's the code I used to check https://gist.github.com/GabiGrin/0698d5c97a7415a85c3dcc9a07fb5e7a

sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-forest-58wbn?file=/src/index.js:0-684

Comment: @GabrielG I don't javascript so I can't point out your error; but you are mistaken. My list is correct.

Comment: I share the same sentiment as GabrielG. However, having nary a shred of understanding on this rotation business, I base this sentiment on whether implementing the rotation produced the result I needed. That is, the first column in the 5 rotations table could get  what I needed, but the first column in the 4 rotation (with Z) could not.

Comment: @NaOH which two different lines (first column) give the same result then?

Comment: Interestingly, more duplicates than I thought: XZ, YX, ZY form one repeated set, while XXZ and XYX forming another... Now that I've the culprits I am thinking maybe this is caused by whether the rotation axis are extrinsic of intrinsic? In my rotations extrinsic was used.

Comment: @NaOH I print them as matrices... So, XZ means you FIRST rotate around the Z-axis and then around the X axis.  If I invert your given lists they become ZX,XY, YZ (line 6) and ZXX, XYX (line 15).

Answer (score 6):

You can use rotation matrices. Rotating a 3D array around the x-axis means that the element at position `(i,j,k)` will be mapped to position `(i,-k,j)`. Of course, if your array is 0-indexed, you probably have to replace `-k` with `size-1-k` or something like that.

Similarly, rotating around the y-axis maps `(i,j,k)` to `(k,j,-i)`. These two rotations can be represented as matrices. For the x-axis rotation:

```
|i'|   |1  0  0| |i|
|j'| = |0  0 -1|*|j|
|k'|   |0  1  0| |k|
```

And for the y-axis rotation:

```
|i'|   |0  0  1| |i|
|j'| = |0  1  0|*|j| 
|k'|   |-1 0  0| |k|
```

Any general rotation can be described as a sequence of those two rotations. Applying two rotations consecutively is just multiplying the 3x3 matrices. So, if you find all possible products of them, you'd get 24 matrices (including the identity), each one corresponds to a valid rotation of your array. It's a little tricky to find all possible multiplications, because they don't commute.

I think you can just brute-force all products of the form `(A^p)*(B^q)*(A^r)*(B^s)`, where A and B are the two matrices before and `p,q,r,s` are their powers, and range from 0 to 3 (exponentiating A or B to 4 will take them back to the identity matrix).

Doing it this way, you can generate all 24 valid rotation matrices, and rotate the 3D array using each one of them, taking the care to shift the negative indexes so that you don't access out of bounds.

Comment: This is what I worked out in my answer (and indeed I wrote a program to brute force it).

Comment: For completeness: Rotating around the z-axis maps (i,j,k) to (j,-i,k). The matrix for that one is: row 0 = `|i'|   |0  1  0| |i|` -- row 1 = `|j'| = |-1 0  0|*|j|` -- row 2 = `|k'|   |0  0  1| |k|`

Answer (score 6):

[James Waldby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837847/james-waldby-jwpat7)'s answer is inspiring, and I want to add a slightly improved version with only two for-loops.

We know that there are 24 unique orientations. I calculated this by imagining a dice: there are 6 possible choices for the top face, and 4 possible rotations for each face on top.

What if we iterate with that idea? I thought. If we can figure out a way to travel all 6 faces of the dice, then we only need to observe the 4 rotations on each face, and we are done!

So I grabbed the nearest "brick" (in my case, a Vitasoy carton) and started rotating to see what would be the easiest pattern to visit all 6 faces. If we introduce an additional counter-clockwise turn, such that our operations are:

- Roll (in a fixed direction, e.g. so that the face facing you is now rotated downwards)
- Turn CW (along a fixed axis, e.g. so that the face facing you is turned clockwise, but still facing you)
- Turn CCW (along the same axis as the last one)

Then we can visit all faces by doing:

Roll -> Turn CW -> Roll -> Turn CCW -> Roll -> Turn CW -> Roll -> Turn CCW -> Roll -> Turn CW -> Roll -> Turn CCW

With the last roll and turn, we are back to the original orientation. As you can see, it is a repeated sequence of roll + alternating CW turns and CCW turns.

Now, if we expand this to include all rotations of each face we visit, this becomes:

Roll -> 3x Turn CW -> Roll -> 3x Turn CCW -> Roll -> 3x Turn CW -> Roll -> 3x Turn CCW -> Roll -> 3x Turn CW -> Roll -> 3x Turn CCW

...and we are back to where we started! This can be translated into two for-loops (one fewer!):

```py
def sequence(m):
  for roll_index in range(6):
    m = roll(m)
    yield(m)
    for turn_index in range(3):
      m = turn_cw(m) if roll_index % 2 == 0 else turn_ccw(m)
      yield(m)
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
import numpy as np

def rotations(array):
    for x, y, z in permutations([0, 1, 2]):
        for sx, sy, sz in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=3):
            rotation_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))
            rotation_matrix[0, x] = sx
            rotation_matrix[1, y] = sy
            rotation_matrix[2, z] = sz
            if np.linalg.det(rotation_matrix) == 1:
                yield np.matmul(rotation_matrix, array)

all_rotations = list(rotations(np.array(array)))
```

Idea is to generate all coordinates relabelings with possible axis' direction changes, ex. (-z, y, x). The question that remains is whether all coordinates relabelings are obtainable from (x, y, z) axes using only rotations. Half of the 6 * (2^3) = 48 labelings aren't because they are rotations of a mirrored version of the (x, y, z) cooridnates (left-handed coordinates, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

Rows of the corresponding rotation matrix `A` of relabeling operation will have only one value in each row. The value determines which axis to select on that index, and whether to flip the axis.

```
A * (x, y, z) = (-z, y, x)

    | 0, 0, -1 |
A = | 0, 1, 0  |
    | 1, 0, 0  |
```

We keep only those rotations, whose `det(A) == 1` meaning that only rotations were applied by the operation. `det(A) == -1` means that it is a rotation with mirroring.