# How to calculate the quaternions of all 24 rotations of a cube?

Tags: python, rotation, quaternions

Similar to these two previous questions ([How to calculate all 24 rotations of 3d array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190042/how-to-calculate-all-24-rotations-of-3d-array), [How to get all 24 rotations of a 3-dimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452383/how-to-get-all-24-rotations-of-a-3-dimensional-array)), I want to find the all the 90 degree rotations of an object. However, I need the quaternions of those rotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
from pyquaternion import Quaternion


def rotations():
    for x, y, z in itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2]):
        for sx, sy, sz in itertools.product([-1, 1], repeat=3):
            rotation_matrix = np.zeros((3, 3))
            rotation_matrix[0, x] = sx
            rotation_matrix[1, y] = sy
            rotation_matrix[2, z] = sz
            if np.linalg.det(rotation_matrix) == 1:
                quat = Quaternion(matrix=rotation_matrix)
                yield quat.elements


all_rotations = list(rotations())

print(len(all_rotations))
for x in all_rotations:
    print(x)
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70413438/11042246) by [Igor Kołakowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10874583) of a similar question.